# C++ enum addition and conversion (Raspberry Pi Pico PIO)

Tags: c++, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to include the Raspberry Pi Pico PIO/i2c example in a library within my larger project (to abstract i2c implementations).  This seems to work just fine when it is included in a primary executable project (like to example).  Within a library, I receive the following compilation error.  `pis_interrupt0` is a member of the pio_interrupt_source enum from the SDK. Both my main project and library project is using C++ -- while the PIO code is using just C.

```
In file included from /src/lib/lib_pico_i2c/pio_i2c.h:9,
                 from /src/lib/lib_pico_i2c/PioI2C.cpp:3:
/src/build/lib/lib_pico_i2c/i2c.pio.h: In function 'void i2c_program_init(PIO, uint, uint, uint, uint)':
/src/build/lib/lib_pico_i2c/i2c.pio.h:87:53: error: invalid conversion from 'uint' {aka 'unsigned int'} to 'pio_interrupt_source' [-fpermissive]
     pio_set_irq0_source_enabled(pio, pis_interrupt0 + sm, false);
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

I suspect it has something to do with C++ conversion rules or a missing included of some sort.  I have tried to manually include the SDK file that defines `pio_interrupt_source` with no change.  I am relatively new with C/C++ (I do c# in my day job).  My reading of C conversion behavior for enums is that there should be an implicit conversion (with no decorations needed).  Does being referenced from a C++ file change this?  I have tried a number of manual conversion methods with no luck.

you can see the code here: [burtonrodman/pico-oled-pio-cpp](https://github.com/burtonrodman/pico-oled-pio-cpp)

Comment: Take the advice given in the error message and compile that file with `-fpermissive`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Paul Saunders,
I have able to fix by adding this to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set_source_files_properties(PioI2C.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -fpermissive)
set_source_files_properties(pio_i2c.h  PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -fpermissive)
```